# octave print all numbers of factorial

Tags: format, octave, factorial

How to print out all digits of 100! in octave?

octave:1> factorial(100)
ans =  9.3326e+157

the command bellow gives incorrect answer:

octave:4> printf("%u\n",factorial(100))
93326215443947553183793338240612302366006877769275129529769934567734921397913148008797092443225880267680360266584467988186500321788890593731926090238149001216

Answer (score 0):

Octave does not support large integers natively, but [Octave-Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/) has a wrapper for GMP.  You might check out Pari-GP as well.